# How to display the content of a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

My Django app sends through AJAX POST/GET communications arrays representing parts of my DB. As you can see on the picture, this is a typical array with all the objects. The objects represent a messages to integrate in a chat box. Just to clarify, the amount of objects might vary, so I need a loop function or smthg to display all the objects within the response array .

Therefore, I need to display these arrays, combining HTML and JS.

[This is my exact AJAX Json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKMCj.png)

HTML:

```
    <div id="display"></div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url : "/checkview",
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                $("#display").empty();
                for (var models_to_return in response.message)
                {
                    var temp="<div class='container darker'><b>"+response.messages[models_to_returney].user_id+"</b><p>"+response.messages[models_to_return].room+"</p><span class='time-left'>"+response.messages[models_to_return].datetime+"</span></div>";
                    $("#display").append(temp);
                }
            },
            error: function(response){
                //alert('An error occured')
            }
        });
    },1000);
    })
</script>
```

But nothing is displaying.

Comment: yes you need to loop array to get object data

Comment: Typo: `models_to_returney` should be `models_to_return`. And you need to loop over `response.models_to_return`, not `response.message`

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url : "/checkview",
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $("#display").empty();
            for (var model in response.models_to_return)
            {
                var temp="<div class='container darker'><b>"+model.user_id+"</b><p>"+model.room+"</p><span class='time-left'>"+model.datetime+"</span></div>";
                $("#display").append(temp);
            }
        },
        error: function(response){
            //alert('An error occured')
        }
    });
},1000);
})
```